# Customers Truncating Querystring, causes FormatException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Every so often at Rentler we see the error

> **System.FormatException**, String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

in our health monitoring. As it turns out, it looks like our customers are occasionally truncating the end of the url when copy/pasting it elsewhere. It just so happens that a boolean parameter tends to be on the end of the string, and when a customer shares it over some social network we get dumped with error reports.

> https://{domain}/search?sid=17403777&nid=651&location=840065&propertytypecode=1&**photosonly=fals**

We use model binding for everything, so I'm not really sure how to deal with this. I could change the property to a string and attempt to parse it in the controller action, but that's sloppy. Is there any simple, fluent way to get the model binder to TryParse() it and just resolve to false if it can't?

Comment: This would be nice to know.  Hope the answer doesn't involve writing your own model binder.

Comment: That is what I'm hoping for, Gromer. It's such an organic, infrequent error, but highly annoying.

Comment: What about creating an overload which has `photosonly` as a string parameter instead of a bool, which just returns the result of calling the normal one with a false?

Comment: I know that your question is specific for other part, but for sharing and email marketings, why not **shorten the URL**, there are dozens of API's for such, and you can even use your own domain name. I use http://bit.ly and I love it, and so my users... in 2012 and we still "post" huge url's ...

Comment: @Dusda, remove the domain in your url in the question so people can't click it (if you don't want people to go to the url).

Comment: We use AddThis for our sharing, and it uses URL shorteners depending on the social network the user is sharing to. However these errors seem to come from people directly copy/pasting the URL, so we have no control over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about custom model binder for boolean data type? you would need something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// A custom model binder for boolean values. This behaves the same as the default
/// one, except it will resolve the value to false if it cannot be parsed.
/// </summary>
public class BooleanModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        //MVC checkboxes need specific handling in checked state
        if (string.Equals(valueResult.AttemptedValue, "true,false"))
        {
            AddToModelState(bindingContext, valueResult);
            return true;
        }

        bool parsed = false;
        if (Boolean.TryParse(valueResult.AttemptedValue, out parsed))
        {
            AddToModelState(bindingContext, valueResult);
            return parsed;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private static void AddToModelState(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, ValueProviderResult valueResult)
    {
        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, new ModelState { Value = valueResult });
    }
}

//in Global.asax
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(bool), new BooleanModelBinder());
}
```

Comment: Nice!  So, I'm assuming this binder will be used even in a complex type that has a `bool` property?  Say you have `class car { public bool IsAwesome { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } }`  It would use the default binder to bind to the `car` argument in my action method, and use the `BooleanModelBinder` when it encounters the `IsAwesome` data coming in in the request?

Comment: Yes, IsAwesome property will be binded with this ModelBinder. Boolean properties will use this particular binder, and the rest of the model binding will go usual way.

Comment: Thanks, Dooh. I figured I'd have to implement a custom binder, but hoped MVC had some dark corner somewhere that would let me configure the default one. Oh well, this is the best approach.

Comment: One warning, though: this model binder will break checkboxes, since by default HTML helpers render both a checkbox and a hidden input field, resulting in the querystring value "true,false" if the checkbox is checked. You can fix it with a simple if statement above the TryParse() line. I submitted an edit of the answer, but it got rejected for some reason :/.

Comment: Dusda thanks for pointing out this checkbox "issue".. I always forget about this MVC behaviour. I have just edited the code to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a try/catch block and have a default value in the catch.

An alternative would be to only check if the first letter of the parameter is 'T' or 'F'. This should avoid a lot of the issues.

Comment: It would be better to TryParse() it than that, but I would prefer to avoid implementing custom validation like that in the controller action, especially since Rentler has multiple integrations with other companies, and thus multiple controller actions I'd have to cover.

Comment: It sounds like this is a very specific problem though, requiring a specific solution. I also do not see any benefit of TryParse to Try/Catch so cannot defend my choice on this.