# MVC 5 checkbox input validation / error handling

Tags: c#, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem validating a bool value in my ViewModel displayed as a checkbox.

ViewModel:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public bool Newsletter { get; set; }
}
```

The View:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Newsletter)
```

I have been trying to build a custom ValidationAttribute to make sure that only true/fales values can be sent to the controller. If someone changes the value of the checkbox, to lets say "asdfg", the submit of the form will result in a 500 error with the following error:
*System.InvalidOperationException! The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'System.Boolean' failed. See the inner exception for more information.*

I have been trying to find a way to avoid this server error, but it seemas that MVC craches before ValidationAttribute is applied.

The only solution to handle this was to use the OnException in the controller. Does anyone know a better way to handle this?

```
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception is InvalidOperationException)
        {
            // Handle this exception here
        }

        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
```

Comment: Show your post method. If you are checking `ModelState` then there will no exception. (But since it would be a malicious user doing it, does not really matter that an exception is thrown)

Comment: And what is your _custom ValidationAttribute_? That should not be necessary for a `boolean` property

Comment: Yes, I'm checking ModelSate in the Controller but MVC "carches" before on ModelBind if I have understood it right. Someone wrote an answer but removed it later on, this answear lead me to a solution using custom ModelBinder for bool. This solution helped me out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12901560/3710233

Comment: The answer was deleted because it was wrong. You do **not** need a custom model binder. The `DefaultModelBinder` will **not** throw an exception. If your getting an exception, it is almost certainly because of your _custom ValidationAttribute_ which you have not shown. Show it so that we can fix the actual problem.

Comment: Stephen, I have removed my custom ValidationAttribute as it did not help, so the bool field does not have any attributes at all except [Display]. And when i manipulate the values like this: <input checked="checked" id="Newsletter" name="Newsletter" type="checkbox" value="asdf">
<input name="Newsletter" type="hidden" value="asdf"> it will genearte "System.InvalidOperationException!" error...

Comment: Are you checking `ModelState` in the POST method? Show your controller methods so we can understand what your doing. Its not the model binder which is throwing an exception. but in any case, I'm not really sure what your concern is. If your using `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Newsletter)` and the posted value is `asdf` it means you have a malicious user manipulating the values so let it throw an exception.

Comment: This is what the action looks like:         [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(UserModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            return View(model);
        }

Comment: I added Response.Write("Test" + model.Newsletter.ToString()); Response.End() inside the if-statment !ModelState.IsValid, and it prints TestFalse... So the crash is after  return View(model)

Comment: Therefore you can check if `ModelState`contains an error for the `Newsletter` property and if so, redirect to an appropriate view.